# SPARQL query to get a node sub graph at n level depth

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am looking to get a sub graph of a given node to a given `k level` of depth as shown in the following image for k=2.

[image]

if I go to https://dbpedia.org/sparql and select a `?city` I want to get all the details of the city graph to say 5 levels. I am looking for a generic query that do not need to have knowledge of the graph to fetch the data like below.

```
CONSTRUCT {
  ?city a ?plebs .
  ?mayor foaf:gender ?gender.
  ?city dbo:country ?ctr .
  ?city dbo:populationTotal ?pop.
  ?city dbo:leaderParty ?party .
  ?city rdfs:label ?cityName .
  ?party dbo:ideology ?ideology 
} WHERE {
   ?plebs rdfs:subClassOf dbo:Settlement.
   ?city a ?plebs .
   ?city (dbp:mayor | dbo:mayor | dbp:leader |dbo:leader | dbo:leaderName) ?mayor .
   ?mayor foaf:gender ?gender.
   ?city dbo:populationTotal ?pop .
   ?city rdfs:label ?cityName .
   ?city dbo:country ?ctr .
   ?city dbo:leaderParty ?party .
   ?party dbo:ideology ?ideology .
   FILTER(str(?gender) = "female")
  }
ORDER BY DESC(?pop)
```

Can someone please help me with a generic SPARQL query that can work on any database for a given node.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: then use variables instead of properties in predicate position. And of course you need nested `OPTIONAL` clauses because of lead nodes and literals that do not have outgoing edges.  Clearly, depth 5 could already mean a large portion of the whole graph. And then what about incoming edges when you have properties used in the other direction? For example, in DBpedia the relation `starring` goes from film to actor

Comment: @AKSW: Thanks for answering, Just to put things in context, if I were to do the same on a Neo4J using their Cypher query, the query would be something as simple as this. `MATCH (c:City)-[1..5:r]-(n) WHERE c.name= "Paris" RETURN c, n, r` I am unable to see how to write something like this in SPARQL

Comment: Right. But SPARQL is not Cypher nor Gremlin nor GraphQL. SPARQL is for RDF, the others are more graph traversal languages. All of them share common features but all of them are also different. There are even some converters, e.g. from SPARQL to Gremlin.

Comment: Just to give you a rough idea: ` ... where {?city ?p1 ?o1 OPTIONAL {?o1 ?p2 ?o2 OPTIONAL {?o2 ?p3 ?o3} } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy:

```
construct {

?s ?p ?o.
?o ?op ?oo.
?oo ?oop ?ooo.
?ooo ?ooop ?oooo.
?oooo ?oooop ?ooooo.
}
where {
bind(city:_London as ?s)
?s ?p ?o.
optional {
   ?o ?op ?oo.
   optional {
      ?oo ?oop ?ooo.
       optional {
          ?ooo ?ooop ?oooo.
          optional {
              ?oooo ?oooop ?ooooo.
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

The construct statement will return the graph of all outbound links from the city in question, and any time you have a null returned, that triple will simply not be constructed.